# Momepy Geodataframe to Shapefile Error with Class 'list'

Tags: shapefile, geopandas, osmnx

I am processing OSM data to calculate straightness of streets in a city. This function in Momepy works perfectly. When I want to save the result (geodataframe) to a shapefile, it gives me an error:
ValueError: Invalid field type <class 'list'

The error is mostly due to OSMID column as I tried to look into datatypes and converted every other attribute column to string and run it. Would it be ok to delete the OSMID column?

I am attaching the result of datatypes in the straightness geodataframe which I am trying to save into shapefile.[data types][1]

Please suggest the steps to save a shapefile correctly
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZ85m.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Coming late with an answer (mostly because there were no relevant tags), so mostly for others coming later.

Shapefile doesn't support lists as a data type. Those need to be converted to something else (string?) or dropped.

You can delete some of the columns if you don't need them anymore, that is not a problem at all. OSM data usually comes with a lot of columns you don't need.